# Angular ng-form group errors

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-form

I have one problem with form and `ng-form`.

Here is the sample https://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/12182/

What I would like to do is display group messages.
eg. If I have 3 items and any are invalid then show the error message outside of `ng-form`.

I don't want to repeat every error message under input. If 3 inputs with name 'number' is invalid, I want to display only one message.

Does anyone have any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out.

https://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/12189/

it works with `angular 1.3+`

but if someone have better solution I will like to see it.

Thanks.